# Acessing The Return Array

Tags: php, arrays, curl, return

edit:

```
<?php
    $file= 'fbplus.jpg';

    $args = array(
       'message' => $album_message,
    );
    $args[basename($file)] = '@' . realpath($file);
    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = $graph_url;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    //returns the photo id
    print_r(json_decode($data,true));


    echo "$data['id'] "; //wont work
        echo "$data[id] "; //wont work


?>
```

this was the return, after i successfully uploaded a photo.

Array ( [id] => 112235735579158 [post_id] => 100003781972892_112203478915717 )

Comment: Isn't that an assoc. array? Should be `$data['id']` instead of `$data[id]`

Comment: If that is the array, then $data['id'] should work.  Also, please use long open tags.  Later down the road when you're stuck on a server that doesn't have short open tags enabled, you'll likely regret it.

Comment: @Smamatti, yes, syntactically, `id` should be in quotes, but that's not what's causing the problem here.

Comment: and also equal sign <?= $data['id']; ?>

Comment: @NADH Alright, thanks! Wasn't sure about the return value, because it stated `mixed` in the API. Guess you are right then in your answer :-)

Comment: @NADH because he want to put it somewhere i html that why he use <? but <? is the same as <?php it's shortcut if you have enabled it in php.ini. and since it not an array as you write in your answer it should be <?= $data ?> or <?= json_encode($data)['id'] ?> but don't think that php allow to use index after a function call. Didn't read question carefully.

Comment: @jcubic, `short_open_tag` (`<? ?>`) is deprecated, and was removed in PHP 5.3.0

Comment: @NADH Oh I din't know what about <?= $var ?>

Comment: @NADH: I think (might be wrong) that jcubic meant that `<?=` is also a short open tag and should also not be used: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use

Comment: @jcubic, `<?= ?>` is valid usage. However, it's only available in PHP 5.4.0+ and in versions before 5.3.0.

Comment: @jcubic: It's only 'valid' if the server has short tags enabled.

Comment: i edited the code. still cant access it. i just had problem posting thats why. its my first post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`curl_exec()` returns a string (contents of the webpage), not an `Array`. So you cannot do `$data['id']` because `$data` is a string and not an array.

What is the url you are posting to? What is its exact output?

EDIT: Looks like the url returns JSON. In that case:

```
<?php
    $file= 'fbplus.jpg';

    $args = array(
       'message' => $album_message,
    );
    $args[basename($file)] = '@' . realpath($file);
    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = $graph_url;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    //returns the photo id

    $data = json_decode($data,true);

    echo $data['id'];
?>
```

Comment: i used this print_r(json_decode($data,true));   the output is  Array ( [id] => 112265748909490 [post_id] => 100003781972892_112203478915717 ) .  then why is it an array?

Comment: Ah, it's an array because you are using `json_decode()` which you did not mention in your original question.

Comment: @RoxyGutera, I've edited my answer with code that works. While you are doing a `json_decode()` inside `print_r()`, you are not assigning it to the `$data` variable!

Comment: the output is { (one curly brace) . whats happening?

Comment: sorry about that i forgot to remove the print_r. thanks NADH it worked

Answer (score 0):

Are you accessing the Facebook Graph API?

If so just use:

```
$data = json_decode($data);
```

and the you can access it trough `$data->id`

Comment: that was my first approach but still $data->id is NULL. yes graph api and $data = json_decode($data); is in my code already. but still i cant access the array

Comment: @Roxy, by default, `json_decode()` returns an object. If you want to get an array, try `json_decode($data, true)`